# Inserting multiple items into DB error

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

I'm not that familiar with Flask/SQLite but I'm trying to insert several items into a DB in one go.

```
g.db.execute('insert into images(fileName, fileTitle, file_height, file_width, file_size) values (?,?,?,?,?)', filename, request.form['title'], fileMetaData['height'], fileMetaData['width'], fileMetaData['fileSize'])
```

running that gives me a

> TypeError: function takes at most 2 arguments (6 given)

What's the best way go go about doing this? I understand the error but I don't understand how I'm supposed to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the arguments must be a tuple:

```
g.db.execute('insert into images(fileName, fileTitle, file_height, file_width, file_size) values (?,?,?,?,?)', (filename, request.form['title'], fileMetaData['height'], fileMetaData['width'], fileMetaData['fileSize']))
```

Comment: It seem to run fine and didn't throw an error at me. Just have to check. It worked, thank you. I was just going by what I read in their Flaskr tutorial.

Comment: It's pedantic, I know, but it's a tuple, rather than a list.

If you ever want to pass just one item, you would need to create a singleton tuple like so:

`g.db.execute("SELECT name FROM users WHERE user_id=?", (user_id,))`

(note the trailing comma ,)